# Bash script not substituting variable as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a shell script which uses a command called jmxquery

This is what works on the command line:

```
[root@monitor jmxquery]# java -jar /opt/jmxquery/jmxquery.jar \
    -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://tomcat.cyberdyne.corp:1099/jmxrmi \
    -O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS MarkSweep' \
    -A LastGcInfo \
    -K GcThreadCount

**JMX OK - LastGcInfo.GcThreadCount=4 | LastGcInfo.GcThreadCount=4**
```

As you can I see i get a JMX OK with thread count details. So I'm trying to do the same within a shell script. I have a variables defined like this:

```
JAR=/opt/jmxquery/jmxquery.jar
JMXHOST=tomcat.cyberdyne.corp
JMXPORT=1099
SERVICE_URL="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://${JMXHOST}:${JMXPORT}/jmxrmi"
attr_marksweep_threadcount="-O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS MarkSweep' -A LastGcInfo -K GcThreadCount"
```

Then I run:

```
java -jar ${JAR} -U ${SERVICE_URL} $attr_marksweep_threadcount
```

Here is a snippet of what the output looks like with bash -x

```
+ attr_marksweep_threadcount='-O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='\''PS MarkSweep'\'' -A LastGcInfo -K GcThreadCount'
+ java -jar /opt/jmxquery/jmxquery.jar -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://spotfirewin75.cyberdyne.corp:1099/jmxrmi -O 'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='\''PS' 'MarkSweep'\''' -A LastGcInfo -K GcThreadCount
**JMX CRITICAL - java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS**
```

As you can see it's chopped off the rest of the command after PS.

How do I get the script to substitute correctly?

Comment: I don't see anything chopped but I don't see `${SERVICE_URL}` being defined anywhere.

Comment: @Julie the variables are defined, I've put them in my post now.

Comment: @drewbenn I get a different result saying the command line options are not recognised.

Comment: I think this problem can be simplified. Consider:

'command="ls -l '/tmp/test/My Directory'"
$command
'
Upon running this I then get:

'
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/My: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Directory': No such file or directory
'

I'm pretty sure if I can solve this problem, i can solve the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this (paraphrasing your shorter example in the comment):

```
mkdir "foo bar"
parms="-l 'foo bar'"
ls $parms
```

The `parms` variable is [word-split](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) along any whitespace, without regard to the quotes, so it becomes
`-l`, `'foo`, and `bar'` (three arguments). 
The original example had the same issue with `attr_marksweep_threadcount`, and ended up with one of the arguments containing `java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS` and the rest of the quoted string in another argument. I'll assume your java didn't like that.

If we quote the variable containing the parameters:

```
ls "$parms"
```

We get `ls` called with `-l 'foo bar'` (one argument). Quoting the variable prevents word-splitting (and filename globbing), but quotes *inside* the variable don't.

It's a bit difficult to work around this problem with simple shell variables, but since Bash has [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays), you could use one and put each argument in a separate element of the array:

```
array=("-l" "foo bar")
ls "${array[@]}"
```

`"${array[@]}"` expands to the equivalent of all the array members, individually quoted.

---

With array-less shells, you have to use some work-arounds. The [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters) can be [expanded with `$@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) similarly to arrays:

```
set -- "-l" "foo bar"
ls "$@"
```

Or, since word-splitting is done only along characters set in `IFS`, we can make the shell split on something other than white-space.

```
IFS=#
parms='-l#foo bar'
ls $parms
# though IFS stays set to the hash sign after this
```

---

The output from `bash -x` in your example tries to show what happens, but since it tries to show in single-quotes a string containing a single-quote, the output is a bit messy. This:
 `'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='\''PS'`
parses as `'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='`, `\'`, and `'PS'` all concatenated together, i.e. two single-quoted strings, and a quoted single-quote. Which looks prettier in double-quotes: `"java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
attr_marksweep_threadcount="-O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS MarkSweep' -A LastGcInfo -K GcThreadCount"
```

with:

```
attr_marksweep_threadcount='-O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name="PS MarkSweep" -A LastGcInfo -K GcThreadCount'
```